# Terminal não inicia pelo Visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, shell

Erro recebido ao tentar abrir o terminal: **O processo de terminal falhou ao iniciar o caminho para o executável (zsh) do shell não é um arquivo de um symlink.**

O SO é Ubuntu.

[image: Tela no momento que tento abrir o terminal]

Answer (score 0):

Um dica, acessa qualquer pasta via terminal e executa o comando:

```
code .
```

Assim o `teminal` vai tentar abri o Visual Studio Code e se estiver precisando de alguma dependência ou configuração ele vai "printar" no terminal.